# How to add view over DialogFragment?

Tags: android, view

I need to show my simple view on the top off all views. There is opened DialogFragment, my view should be over it.

I try

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
viewGroup.addView(myView);

myView.bringToFront();
viewGroup.requestLayout();
viewGroup.invalidate();
```

But DialogFragment is still over myView.

Comment: I've the same problem. Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Show your view as Another DialogFragment .

Comment: myView is custom view, like Toast and is used without FragmentManager. So it will be better to have another way, without using one more DialogFragment